# Adding hash item C

Tags: c, hash

There is a strange behaviour on my code. I made a simple function to add an item on a hash with open addressing, but it's simple not working as it should. I removed some content just for clarity of my problem.

```
typedef struct {

    // Documents id
    int *doc;
    // Number of docs
    int numdocs;
    // Word
    char *w;

} Words;

typedef struct {

    // Number of words
    int wordsnum;
    // Table size
    long tamtab;
    // Content
    Words *words;

} HashTable;

void addToTable(HashTable *h, char *w, int doc) {

    int func = HashFunction(*h, w);
    int pos = func;
    int i;
    Words t;

    for( i = 1; h->words[pos].w != NULL && !strcmp(h->words[pos].w, w); i++ ) 
        pos = func + i/2 + i*i/2;

    t = h->words[pos];

    if(t.w == NULL) {

        h->wordsnum++;

        t.w = malloc(sizeof(w));
        strcpy(t.w, w);
        t.numdocs = 1;
        t.doc = malloc(sizeof(int));
        t.doc[0] = doc;

    }
}
```

But when I change it to:

```
void addToTable(HashTable *h, char *w, int doc) {

    int func = HashFunction(*h, w);
    int pos = func;
    int i;

    for( i = 1; h->words[pos].w != NULL && !strcmp(h->words[pos].w, w); i++ ) 
        pos = func + i/2 + i*i/2;

    if(h->words[pos].w == NULL) {

        h->wordsnum++;

        h->words[pos].w = malloc(sizeof(w));
        strcpy(h->words[pos].w, w);
        h->words[pos].numdocs = 1;
        h->words[pos].doc = malloc(sizeof(int));
        h->words[pos].doc[0] = doc;

    }
}
```

It behaves exactly as expected.
My problem, for example, is that `t.numdocs` does not change `h->words[pos].numdocs`. Shouldn't `t` point to same address as `h->words[pos]`, so a change on `t` makes a change o `h->words[pos]`?

EDIT@@@@@

I fixed it! Thank you for the comments:

```
void addToTable(HashTable *h, char *w, int doc) {

    int func = HashFunction(*h, w);
    int pos = func;
    int i;
    Words *t;

    for( i = 1; h->words[pos].w != NULL && !strcmp(h->words[pos].w, w); i++ ) 
        pos = func + i/2 + i*i/2;

    t = &h->words[pos];

    if(t->w == NULL) {

        h->wordsnum++;

        t->w = malloc(sizeof(w));
        strcpy(t->w, w);
        t->numdocs = 1;
        t->doc = malloc(sizeof(int));
        t->doc[0] = doc;

    }
}
```

Comment: `t` is a struct not a pointer, so it does not point anywhere. `t = h->words[pos];` here you make a copy.

Comment: Look closely at your code: in the first version you test `t = h->words[pos]` against `NULL` and in the second you test `h->words[pos].w` for `NULL`.